# How to get specific object from array of objects and delete it at the same time in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, filter

I have an array of sutom objects of type Card:

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :color
end
```

I have another class that has array of **'Card's** I am trying to write a method that takes a Card object as argument and takes it from the array(if available) and returns it as at the same time this object has to be deleted from the array of objects. E.g.:

array_of_cards = [card1, card2, card3, card4]

```
def take_card card_to_be_taken
  #here from array_of_cards I have to pick the card
  #that has rank and color the same as 'card_to_be_taken' and 
  #delete it from the array
end
```

I tried like this:

```
def take_card a
  to_be_pushed = array.delete_if{|card| (card.rank==a.rank and card.color==a.color)}
end
```

but to_be_pushed gets the value of an array of all the cards different than the one that I am looking for.

Comment: It's because `delete_if` returns array **without** deleted item. In other words, it modify **in place** array. ps. I'm not sure, but if something won't work it might be `and`.

Comment: What is "sutom"? I cannot parse your question. It is not clear where the sentence ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you want is [Array#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete).

```
a = [ "a", "b", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.delete("b")                   #=> "b"
a                               #=> ["a", "c"]
a.delete("z")                   #=> nil
a.delete("z") { "not found" }   #=> "not found"
```

especially if you want the same behavior for duplicate elements.

Comment: I dont have duplicates in my array. I have tried your way but this way it deletes all four cards that have the same rank. So this one doesn't work for me. it is not array of string but array of USER DEFINED objects.

Comment: @user2128702 seems a little weird, you mean `array_of_cards.delete(card1)` returns an empty array?

Comment: As for objects (probably there are exception) xlembouras' example works very good (so +1). Here is how I played around it: `class B;
  attr_accessor :val1;
  def initialize val1;
    @val1=val1;
  end;
end;
arr1 = [B.new(1), B.new(2), B.new(3), B.new(2), B.new(1)];
card1 = arr1[1];
arr1.delete card1;
arr1`

Answer (score 0):

`delete` seems to work for me. You might need to overload `==` (if delete is not working well, this is where to look)

If you're ruby pre 2.0, change your `initialize` as my syntax is not valid before Ruby 2.0

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :color

  def initialize(rank: nil, color:nil)
    @rank, @color = rank, color
  end

  def ==(card2)
    @rank == card2.rank && @color == card2.color
  end
end

mycards = [ Card.new(rank: 2, color: :red), Card.new(rank: 9, color: :black) ] 

card = mycards.delete( Card.new(rank: 2, color: :red))
puts card
puts mycards.length
```

Returns:

```
=> #<Card:0x007f8a296ff2d8 @color=:red, @rank=2>
#<Card:0x007f8a296ff2d8>
1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to `pop` but that method delete number of arguments.

Here is the way of build it with `delete_if`:

In your code:

```
to_be_pushed = array.delete_if{|card| (card.rank==a.rank and card.color==a.color)}
```

can be changed to:

```
ret_value = []
array.delete_if do |card| 
if(card.rank==a.rank and card.color==a.color)
  ret_value << card
  true
end
ret_value
```

This way your method returns cards & delete that cards from your array.
ps. I assumed that your method words as you described.